# How to display menus item in line using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've create menu navigation for website.
The result I've got is same as below image.
But my menu-items are not in same line

'HTML`:

```
<ul class="cd-secondary-nav">
    <li class="go-back"><a href="#0"> Back </a></li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>CooVoices</a></li>
    <li class="has-children "> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>ឃូខល</a>
        <ul class="is-hidden">
            <li class="go-back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
            <li><span class="mclose glyphicon glyphicon-remove red"></span></li>
            <li> <a class="" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>International Call</a></li>
            <li> <a class="" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>Tariff</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>CooSufr</a></li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>Camtalk</a></li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>CooBill</a></li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>CooVoice</a></li>
    <li> <a class="" href=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok mcolor "></span>COOMARTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Resultant `menu-items`

[image]

[image]
Please help.

Comment: Can you share your CSS ?

Comment: I guess you are using Bootstrap, is it ?

Comment: do you have any demo link?

Comment: The css used to come to your result is required to find your problem. No CSS? No solution.

Comment: Here is a demo pages which you click on Services You will see that menus 
look like 
http://cootel.com.kh/demo/services/coocall

Comment: @Cambodiachannel Couldn't see THE issue there.

Comment: why not you can check and click on Services

Comment: Now I've upload new images you can see in question

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Cambodiachannel Does this work for you `.cd-secondary-nav ul {position: absolute;}`.

Comment: @Cambodia channel atleast you need to provide some of the css code it is not the full code provided wit your problem

Comment: @Cambodiachannel You still there or left? You might wanna look at our answers and say something.

Comment: Please wait I testing right now

Comment: I can't input css inside of my question so I share it from Google you can see it now 
https://script.google.com/d/1rSUh11Oi3z0UuQGoTV08eIbJ8_IwTKjYJoavld2yRSi7PMmtDlbHRuZe/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got your issue. The secondary nav is missing `position: absolute`. Try this:

```
.cd-secondary-nav ul {position: absolute;}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is so simple
use you class which on is for li thats it

```
li {
  display: inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add display: inline; to your style.css at line 4937 under

```
.cd-primary-nav .cd-secondary-nav > li
```